# Does wireshark detect all unauthorized access?

Tags: wireshark, log-analysis

A security engineer told me that my computer must have a trojan horse, but it has not been found yet.

The security engineer captured and analyzed traffic pcap files with Wireshark, and said that there was a problem in the pcap file.

The security engineer said that since Wireshark captures all traffic, there is no way to miss detecting unauthorized access. However, he said that the ability to detect unauthorized access depends on the skill of the engineer.

However, based on my situation, I feel that wireshark is not able to detect it. In other words, I feel that an engineer's skill is irrelevant.

Is it possible for a hacker to hide IP from wireshark during unauthorized access?

Comment: There's a lot here to unpack, but I edited the details to only the details that support the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

Remote unauthorised access has to come over the network, and a packet capture will show all connections. Hence, the packet capture must capture all unauthorised access.

**However**, network traffic is complex and it is easy for remote access to hide among normal traffic. So the question is, "is it possible to detect and analyse all forms of unauthorised access in a pcap?" And the answer is "no".

It *can be* as simple as spotting an incoming connection with OS commands from a known bad source, if you are lucky (and the hacker hasn't updated their techniques in 20 years).

But incoming connections are not the norm. Infected machines (with trojans) connect *out* to permit unauthorised access, in a process called a "reverse shells". Reverse shells use many tricks to hide and be difficult to detect, including encryption, small data transfers, using compromised 3rd party machines, and even making the unauthorised access look like normal traffic.

Skill goes a long way to expose various factors used to hide the unauthorised access, for sure. But skill is not always sufficient.

So, if a reverse shell uses a compromised normal server, encryption, and small, short bursts, it might not be possible to detect the unauthorised access. It might be possible to determine that there is "something strange", but not enough to **confirm** that there is successful access.

So, to return to your question,

> [Is] there no way to miss detecting unauthorized access

No. It's like saying "I know every birthday since there are only 356 of them." that might be true, but that does not mean that you know any specific person's birthday. The pcap will have the unauthorsed access, but that does not mean that it is possible to determine if it is a successful access, a failed attempt, or an anomaly.

> Is it possible for a hacker to hide IP from wireshark

Which IP? A typical attack can involve many different IPs. The IP that is the last in the chain to access your machine can't be "hidden". The IP that the attacker personally uses at the start of the chain is typically always "hidden" behind many other IPs in the chain.

Comment: "a packet capture will show all connections" is not necessarily true, if the capture is being done on the compromised computer.  It would have to be done in other on-path network equipment.  From the question it isn't clear where the capture was performed.

Comment: In what context would it not be true? As far as I know, it would require a severely compromised network adapter firmware rewrite at a level not used for opportunistic attacks.

Comment: As just one example, a vulnerability leveraging Intel AMT ("hardware-based remote management") would not be visible to any software running on the CPU.

Comment: More generally applicable, without having any special NIC firmware, a rootkit could hijack the API calls that pcap uses to communicate with the network drivers, and filter out the malicious traffic.  Rootkits already hide files and running processes from enumeration, I see no reason that modifying pcap results would be any more challenging.

Comment: @BenVoigt I understand all that, but so far, that's speculation and would require a level of advanced techniques not seen for opportunistic attacks, like I said.

Comment: When you say possibility of undetectability, does that mean wireshark can't detect it? or depending on the engineer skills. Which do you mean?

Comment: @john-trmb Please refer to my birthday analogy. The data will be there in the pcap, but not necessarily in a form to be able to "detect" a specific intrusion. In short, packet captures can help, but are not always conclusive. Things are not black and white.

Comment: Excuse me. I didn't quite understand the meaning of the birthday analogy. but If it's not clear from the packet capture, what should I use instead? Would snort or something help?

Comment: As I have said, the data will be in the pcap but not necessarily in a format to be useful to determine the details of the access. Snort will only work if the traffic is decrypted to be able to inspect the packets.

Comment: i got it. It's very hard to detect malicious packets with wireshark these days, unless hacker probably buying known software, malware from the dark web.